nginx errors showing in production instead of laravel errors
I have a server deployed with the LEMP stack and it's running a laravel application.  When I encounter an error (404 or 419 thus far) I'm seeing the nginx error page instead of a laravel styled error page.  Any idea how to fix this or is this working as designed?

It's not intended but locally you'd typically have APP_DEBUG enabled so you'd see the stack trace. In production you should check this to make sure you've placed your error pages in the correct place

You need add in your nginx config file:
error_page 404 /index.php;
Complete exemple:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /srv/example.com/public;
 
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
 
    index index.php;
 
    charset utf-8;
 
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
 
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
 
    error_page 404 /index.php;
 
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_hide_header X-Powered-By;
    }
 
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

Please, check the Laravel docs.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/deployment#nginx
